What is the correct way to solve "Sub file not found" in typeshed?
I'm trying to add some type hints to typeshed but the package I'm targeting depends on ply and it seems there is no types-ply package.  What is the correct way to handle this, given I want to have hints like:
def my_function(what: int) -> Lexer:

where Lexer is a class defined in the ply package?
